# Hide go to top element when user stops scrolling, show again when starts scrolling again

Tags: javascript

I am using the [code](https://lsj.gr/wiki/MediaWiki:Scroll-to-Top.js) below for a go to top button. I want to be able to hide the element also when a user stops scrolling, and then have it reappear when starts scrolling again. It should preserve not displaying the element at all when `document.body.scrollTop > 300` (as it does now).

```
/* Insert Top Button after Body Content */
$(function() {
  $('<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top"></button>').insertAfter('div#mw-content-text');
});

// When users scroll down 300px, show the Top button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
    document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When users click on Top button, scroll up
function topFunction() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not exactly what you are looking for, but there is not perfect function for this. The closest you can get is listening for the onScroll event, and after 1/2 a second of not scrolling, set a variable to false. EX:

```
   var notScroll = setInterval(function(){userIsScrolling = false;},500);

    window.onscroll = function (e)
    {
        userIsScrolling = true;
    clearInterval(notScroll);
var notScroll = setInterval(function(){userIsScrolling = false;},500);
    }
```

EDIT:
Revised Version:

```
/* Insert Top Button after Body Content */
$(function() {
  $('<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top"></button>').insertAfter('div#mw-content-text');
});

// When users scroll down 300px, show the Top button
window.onscroll = function (e)
        {
            userIsScrolling = true;
        clearInterval(notScroll);
    var notScroll = setInterval(function(){userIsScrolling = false;},500);
        }

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
    document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When users click on Top button, scroll up
function topFunction() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can that be incorporated in the existing code?

Comment: I revised it, let me know if it works, if not i might have to fix something, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it, it shows no button at all.